# core-plot Gesture Recognizer Failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, core-plot, uipangesturerecognizer

I put the core - the plot chart added to a UIScrollView, and then added to a view in the ViewController, then I put the view of the ViewController added to another contains the pan gesture in the view of a ViewController, now the core - the plot chart will not be able to slide, pan gestures can perform, how in the sliding core - the plot chart, not affected by the influence of the pan gesture，thank you
@Eric Skroch

Sorry, my poor english...
I met like the same situation in the following figure, when sliding around core-plot chart of touch event can not be executed, but the implementation of the pan gesture, I would like to achieve when the finger is not affected when the slide chart pan gesture.Can you understand me?
[image]

Comment: This question is not readable. Pay some attention to "how" you write, because we try to understand your text and give you our time to solve the issue. There is `.` sign in each language, you should use it ;)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want the Core Plot graph to respond to scroll and/or zoom gestures while in a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: I've added a more detailed description.Can you understand me?